# Does this sort have a name?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I had to find what that mystery algorithm does. Now I know it's a sort, but I can't find an official name for it.

Here is its Java code:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < myListSize; i++) {
    min = Collections.min(myList.subList(i, myListSize));
    minIndex = myList.indexOf(min);
    Collections.reverse(myList.subList(minIndex, myListSize));
    Collections.reverse(myList.subList(i, myListSize));
}
```

Take this array:

```
   [G,E,D,A,F,C,H,I,B]
```

It 1) searches for the min. element, 2) reverses the subarray from there and 3) reverses the whole thing again:

```
1) [G,E,D,[A,F,C,H,I,B]]
2) [G,E,D,[B,I,H,C,F,A]]
3) [[A,F,C,H,I,B],D,E,G]
```

Now the min. element is on the left. Repeat for the remainder of the array:

```
1) [A] [F,C,H,I,[B,D,E,G]]
2) [A] [F,C,H,I,[G,E,D,B]]
3) [A] [[B,D,E,G],I,H,C,F]

1) [A,B] [D,E,G,I,H,[C,F]]
2) ...
```

and voilà! Sorted. Do you have a name for it, please ?

Comment: It's not at all clear why it's doing the reversal at all. Without that, it's just a selection sort...

Comment: It looks like a stupid version of selection sort, but substring reversal might be actually faster than swapping two elements in some unusual string implementation (such as DNA: affix reversal = one splice, substring exchange = four splices)

Comment: Indeed. I guess it was entirely invented for educational purpose. Well, I'll go for "inefficientSelectionSort" then...

Comment: if we go with the DNA model, then the best approach is selection sort with substring reversal (one cross-over per selection step)

Comment: Trivia: Guess who is involved in this algorithm. Its Bill Gates. http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~christos/papers/Bounds%20For%20Sorting%20By%20Prefix%20Reversal.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called [Pancake sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting).

[image: Pancake sorting, Image from wikipedia]

Here's a code golf puzzle about it: [Flipping pancakes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12028/flipping-pancakes)

Comment: OOH! Thank you so much. Now I'm hungry. :)

Comment: Trivia: Guess who is involved in this algorithm. Its Bill Gates. http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~christos/papers/Bounds%20For%20Sorting%20By%20Prefix%20Reversal.pdf